# ojAlgo: slice or extract sub-matrix

Tags: java, slice, linear-algebra, submatrix, ojalgo

In the java library `ojAlgo`, how can I slice a matrix or extract a sub-matrix from an existing one?

For example, 
`matrix A = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]`.

I am looking for a method which looks like `slice(a,b,c,d)` where a, b are the start and end indexes of the rows and c,d are the start and end indexes of the columns.

For example, if I call `A.slice(1,3,1,3)`, it should return `[[5,6],[8,9]]`.

I tried the `slice` method in `SparseStore`, but it does not work as I expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "slice" methods always return something 1D. You can slice out an index range, row, column, diagonal...

If you want a sub-view of a matrix you can do it this way:

```
matrix.logical().limits(3, 3).offsets(1, 1).get();
```

or with your example since the original matrix is 3x3, it's enough to do:

```
matrix.logical().offsets(1, 1).get();
```

Comment: With recent versions of ojAlgo you can skip 'logical()' and 'get()'. In the 3x3 case you simply do: matrix.offsets(1, 1);